# Searching for the first matching element after a specific node (XPath and ITunes XML)

Tags: java, xml, xpath, itunes

it's not nessesary to post my full code because I have just a short questions. I'm searching with XPath in a XML Doc for a text Value. I have a XML Like

```
<key>Name</key>
<string>Dat Ass</string> 
<key>Artist</key>
<string>Earl Sweatshirt</string> 
<key>Album</key>
<string>Kitchen Cutlery</string> 
<key>Kind</key>
<string>MPEG-Audiodatei</string>
```

I have an Expression like this:

```
//string[preceding-sibling::key[text()[contains(., 'Name')]]]/text()
```

but this gives me ALL following string-tags, I just want the first one with the Song-Title.

greets Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use**:

```
(//string[preceding-sibling::key[1] = 'Name'])[1]/text()
```

**Alternatively, one can use a forward-only expression:**

```
(//key[. = 'Name'])[1]/following-sibling::string[1]/text()
```

**Do note**:

This is a common error. Any expression of the kind:

```
//someExpr[1]
```

Doesn't select "the first node in the document from all nodes selected by `//someExpr`". In fact it can select *many* nodes.

The above expression selects any node that is selected by `//someExpr` and that is the first such child of its parent.

This is why, without brackets, the other answer to this question is generally incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add another predicate `[1]` to select the first matching node. The nested predicate using `text()` should be unneccessary:

```
//string[preceding-sibling::key[contains(., 'Name')]][1]/text()
```

Another, perhaps more efficient, way to select this node would be

```
//key[contains(., 'Name')]/following-sibling::*[1][self::string]
```

This selects the first node (with any name) following the wanted `key` node and tests if its name is `string`.